# Rotation of Sprite in touch event

Tags: ios, rotation, sprite-kit, game-physics

How am i able to rotate a SpriteNode in the touch event?

Here the code that've got so far:

```
 // Detect what side of the screen the user has touched.
 if(touchLocation.x < 160) { 
   // They've touched the left side (the car turns  left)
   [car runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:-50 duration:0]];
   [car.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(-20,0)];
   car.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(-20, 0);

 }else{
   // They've touched the right side (the car turns right)
   [car runAction:[SKAction rotateByAngle:50 duration:0]];
   [car.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(20,0)];
   _bird.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(20, 0);
 }
```

The rotation for -50 doesn't work, even though other Stackoverflow questions have given that as an accepted answer. Also the working normal 50 degree turn seems to work for a split second then revert back to its original place.

How would I get the rotation to stick and rotate smoothly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you use `rotateByAngle` it's in radians.  theres about ~6 radians in a circle.  so you're rotating this sprite many times over.  It isn't a 50 degree turn the way you'd expect.  You need to be using variations of `CGFloat(M_PI)`.  If you want to convert between degrees and radians the conversion is

```
let radians = CGFloat(M_PI) * degrees / 180.0
```

start there and then see if the sprite behaves in a more predictable way

since your duration for your animation is 0 there is really no reason to use an action there.. can you just set

```
car.zRotation = radians
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that! However it's still doing the same thing with it instantly reverting back to 0 degrees? Is it poor practice/incorrect to place an animation in the touch event?

Comment: probably need to see more code related to your car, but i just added a little bit to my answer

Comment: zRotation fixed it all! Thanks.